# ADFS 2.0 Token-Signing certificate grace period

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

My ADFS token-signing (and token-decrypting) certificate is in the process of auto-rolling over - the secondary cert got generated last night and now shows in the ADFS console. The option to promote it to Primary (right-click on the cert, "Set as Primary") is greyed out, I assume because AutoCertificateRollover is enabled.

I know I have 5 days of a grace period, at the end of which the Secondary will be promoted to Primary. My question is, does the secondary cert actually get used during this 5 day stretch, or does it start getting used at the end, when it gets promoted? We have a few RPs that we need to update with the new CER manually, and I want to know whether this can happen now (inside the 5 day grace period) or a the end, when the secondary gets promoted. The former would be nice, because if it is the latter, that would mean I will have to update the RPs as soon as it rolls over, otherwise, if I am not mistaken, there will be an outage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both certs will be in the metadata and WIF allows you to have more than one cert. in the web.config. 
So the old one will be used until the switchover, then the new one will be used.

Comment: Thanks! So basically the new cert is standing by, and made available to any RPs that can connect to the metadata XML and they should/will update automatically. For any others who do not or cannot, I will have to manually update them within 8 hours or less (SsoLifetime being 480 by default) of the [Cert Expiration-5 days] time. Does that sound right?

Comment: Not sure - we always end up with some downtime :-( To avoid doing this so often, amend the duration - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4588.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-modify-the-duration-of-autocertificaterollover-certificates.aspx

Comment: Yup, I did took care of that already. :) I wonder if upping the SsoLifetime, temporarily, to something like 48 or 72 hours would be a way to sidestep the downtime... It is sort of a tradeoff between security and service availability, I suppose, but I don't see why not, if it is controlled. I will research some more and post anything useful back here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing - it turns out the grace period is actually 5 days, not 15. I got mislead by a blog and did not confirm with multiple sources... For RPs that can read the metadata, it was indeed a piece of cake - they all updated without issues. The ones that I had to update manually, was a but of a race - the window is 60 min from the time of the cert rollover (Event ID 335 in the AD FS\Admin event log of the primary ADFS server). This is guided by the TokenLifetime value, you can get it with "Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust | select -Property Name, TokenLifetime | ft -AutoSize".